# Unable to install my own app: This app is incompatible with all of your devices

Tags: android, google-play, installation

I have a newly uploaded app.  I have had it installed on both my Android phone and Android tablet while developing but have now uninstalled it from both of my devices and yet still can't install from the Play Store.

I get the famous "This app is incompatible with all of your devices." message.

I see that it has been installed on one device by someone else.  However, I am unable to install it on my own devices.

I have looked at other occurrences of this messages on Stack Overflow but don't see anything that seems to relate.  Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: What is devices API version and application minSdkVersion?

Comment: Can you once check your manifest file for support screens option ?

Comment: minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 23

Comment: From the build.gradle file

minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 23

Should this also be in the AndroidManifest.xml file?

No support screen option shown in the manifest file.

Comment: I see that the Support Screen option in the manifest file is optional.  I did  created a new version, just to bump the version number but still have the same issue.

For what it matters, my phone and tablet are on Android version 6.  The app works fine when executed from Android Studio.  I have no idea what the issue is.

Again, I see from the download statistics page that someone has been able to download the app.  I don't know how to troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer.  I didn't realize that one couldn't "buy" one's own app.  I had just wanted to have an end to end test, even if I had to pay for my own app.  so, that is all there was to it.

I wish that were made more obvious somewhere.

Comment: It would also be nice if Google would display an accurate error message instead of one that is misleading.